# how to evenly distribute a CardView in android

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-cardview

In my .XML layout file, how can I evenly distribute a cardview so that there are 3 parts and each of them has 2vertical textviews in it ? I wrote the following code but all the texts are under each other. the picture below is what I want it to look like :
[image: this is what I want the Cardview to look like]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="83dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ConstraintLayout` to easily make the view evenly distribute vertically or horizontally. And you should have 3 Card views instead of just 1. Each of the `CardView` will contain the `TextView` you want to show.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

      >

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardone"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cardtwo"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
          app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/black"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/green"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="textviewone" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/green"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:text="textviewone" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardtwo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cardView"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cardone"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/green"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:text="textviewone" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/green"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="textviewone" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cardtwo"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/green"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:text="textviewone" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/green"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="textviewone" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```